# What square-summable sequences are "sinc-summable"?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

$\operatorname{sinc} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \;\;$ is defined by $\;\; \operatorname{sinc}(x) \; = \; \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }\:\;x=0 \\ \\ \frac{\operatorname{sin}(x)}x & \text{else} \end{cases} \;\; $ .

For what square-summable sequences $\langle x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,...\rangle$ of complex numbers is it the case that

$\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0^+} \left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \: (\operatorname{sinc}(n\cdot h)\cdot x_n)\right) \; $ exists and is finite?

(In other words, when is it the case that the Lebesgue mean at zero of a member of $\; \operatorname{L}_2[-\pi,\pi] \;$

exists and is finite, in terms of the coefficients of that member's exponential fourier series?)

Comment: I know that the answer is at least the absolutely summable sequences.

Comment: When you ask for the existence of the limit, is the infinite sum being understood in the usual sense of $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N$?

Comment: Why don't we go from the other end: what condition would you be happy with? If you formulate it, we can prove or disprove its sufficiency. As stated, the question can be given many answers all of which can easily miss the point you have in mind entirely. 

Comment: @Yemon: The series converges unconditionally for all square-summable sequences and positive $h$, so I don't think it matters.

Comment: @fedja:  My first hope would be that it's exactly the (conditionally) summable sequences.  The "point I have in mind" is something that would be easy to work with in the Hilbert space $\ell^2$ (i.e., without considering the associated square-integrable functions). (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) If I need to be more specific, I would probably be looking for something like "the series such that all of the sub-series formed by taking indices in an arithmetic progression are summable" or "the summable series such that for [some condition on $c$], the sums of the terms from $m$ to $m+n$, where $n<a\cdot m^c$, have a bound that does not depend on $m$ or $n$".

Comment: Note that any continuous at $0$ square summable function would do and those can have terrible Fourier partial sums at $0$, so the class is huge and includes many series that diverge in the classical sense. 